# Different elements in one animation

Tags: css, animation

Their is bit complications but I think it isn't possible to do what I want with just CSS3 alone.

I have three images in header, I want images to show up with `fade-in fade-out` effect by using `opacity` in CSS animation.

I was thinking what if I could select nested elements in animation and animate them. Creating chain animation is bit difficult.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want images to change with `fade in fade out effect`

Comment: Does my answer fix your problem? What is it you want different? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) property to delay the animation.

Comment: Well for an actual _animation_, you might rather want to use [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) ...

Comment: That's what I am figuring out how to smooth animation between deferent element.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply animation rules to your images. Using `animation-delay` a `chain` effect can be produced.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000;
}
img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 33.333%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes fade {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
img:nth-child( 2 ) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
img:nth-child( 3 ) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iyzGnF9.jpg">

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iyzGnF9.jpg">

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iyzGnF9.jpg">
```

Comment: I was already figuring how to use animation delay, let's try this trick.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes. I wanted one image to fade out and other fade in, similarly for third image.

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer if this helps you, otherwise let me know how to tweak it to better answer you question.

Comment: Let me check first, I will reply within few hours

Comment: Sorry friend, it did not gave me the desired results and I had to use JavaScript to do this job. Thanks for your time.